# Finding the inverse of $\bar{x}$ in $\bar{E}.$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory

Here is the question I am trying to understand the solution of letter $(c)$ in it:

Let $x^3 - 2x + 1$ be an element of the polynomial ring $E = \mathbb Z[x]$ and use the bar notation to denote the passage to the quotient ring $\mathbb Z[x]/(x^3 - 2x + 1).$ Let $p(x) = 2x^7 - 7x^5 + 4x^3 - 9x + 1$ and let $q(x) = (x - 1)^4.$\

$(a)$ Express each of the following elements of $\overline E$ in the form $\overline{f(x)}$ for some polynomial $f(x)$ of degree $\leq 2: \overline{p(x)}, \overline{q(x)}, \overline{p(x) + q(x)}$ and $\overline{p(x)q(x)}.$

$(b)$ Prove that $\overline{E}$ is not an integral domain.

$(c)$ Prove that $\overline{x}$ is a unit in $\overline{E}$.

Here is the solution I found online here https://linearalgebras.com/solution-abstract-algebra-exercise-7-4-17.html:

> [image]

My question is:

Why the inverse of $\bar{x}$ should be of degree at most 2, could someone clarify this to me please?

Comment: Because every element of your quotiented ring can be represented by a polynomial of degree $\leq 2$. It is not specific of $\bar{x}$. This can be achieved through euclidean division

Comment: $x^3-2x+1 = 0\Rightarrow -x(x^2+2) = 1$ so $x^{-1} = -(x^2+2)\,$ by uniqueness of inverses. Your [prior question's](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4766165/242) answers showed every polynomial is congruent to its remainder $\!\bmod x^3-2x+1,\,$ which has degree $\le 2.\,$ This is a dupe and will soon be closed

Comment: There is no need compare coef's as in the (very poor) solution. Find a better source to learn algebra.

Comment: @julio_es_sui_glace how did you know that **every element in $\bar{E}$  ......**? is there a proof for this?

Comment: @BillDubuque I do not think that the previous question showed that **every** polynomial is ......

Comment: What did you not understand in the [explanation in the dupe to the prior?](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/628232/242) In any case that play no role here as I mention above, since $\,-(x^2+2)$ *already has degree $\le 2,\,$* i.e. it is already in normal form.

Comment: @BillDubuque The solution "pulls the inverse out of thin air."  The balance of that part of the answer is intended to motivate that selection.

Comment: @Robert It's not ad-hoc: to invert $\,x$ mod $f\,$ simply divide $f\,$ by $x$ to get  $\,f = x g +  c\,,\ c=f(0),\,$ so $\bmod f\!:\ xg \equiv -c\Rightarrow x(-g/c)\equiv 1\Rightarrow x^{-1}\equiv -g/c \equiv (1-\hat f)/x,\ \ \hat f = f/f(0).\,$ This is a special (one step) case of using the extended Euclidean algorithm to compute the inverse, as explained [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3647019/242). Using undetermined coef's works but is brute force and unenlightening (and it is redundant to do so *after* they already found the inverse (presumably) the way I described).

Comment: Said more simply: $\,f = x\:\!(\overbrace{f_n x^{n-1}+\cdots + f_2 x +  f_1}^{\textstyle\color{#c00} g}) + f_0\,\Rightarrow\, x^{-1}\equiv -\color{#c00}g/f_0\pmod{\!f}\ \ $  Presumably their strange notation means $\,\bar x (\overline{-x^2+2})=\bar 1,\,$ i.e. $\,\bar x(- \bar g) = \bar c,\,$ a coset notation form of my above proof (in congruence language). $\ \ $